# multiple registration of transport in xmpp protocol

Tags: xmpp, gateway

I am working on xmpp protocol and I came across with [Gateway](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0100.html) concept, in which it allows to communicate to services which uses another protocol like msn,aim,yahoo etc ..
As far as I understand I beleive that it allows only 1 registration for a particular gateway at a time.For example I can register only 1 msn account at a time.I'am not sure if its really true.

Is it possible to register more that 1 account for a particular gateway and how?Please help me with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is true. All gateways I know (e.g. [spectrum](http://spectrum.im/)) only allow one registration per instance. But you can run multiple instances of the smae gateway type e.g.:

```
icq1.jabberserver.com
icq2.jabberserver.com
```

That is, additional to run mutliple gateway components to different IM neworks, like

```
gtalk.jabberserver.com
irc.jabberserver.com
icq.jabberserver.com
msn.jabberserver.com
...
```

you also run multiple instances of the same [gateway component](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0100.html) on your server. Please not that this are (internal and/or [external](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html)) components to your XMPP server and not individual XMPP servers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply,first of all I think it is not possible to have 2 servers like you mentioned..may be we can have different login of the same protocol with different domains within our servers.
And also it resists upto 2 login's.at the same time I can not display icq1,ic2,icq3 when client is dicovering service info for my servers.

Comment: kiddo: I think you don't understand the concept I am talking about. I have updated my answer. Also, any standard's compliant XMPP client should list the gateways (icq1, icq2, icq3, ...)

Comment: i understand what you are trying to say.Say for example when the client is discovering my server features and I display all the above you stated(icq1,icq2, and rest all protocols that i support), now If I have 3 icq accounts to sigin in through gateway,I have to add another gateway icq3,is'nt correct? what am wondering is, will it be possible to do that in 1 icq gateway.I will have only 1 gateway for icq protocol, but multiple login should be allowed.is that possible?

Comment: I can handle multiple instances in server, but how would the client differentiate the difference b/w the accounts(myicqacc2@icq.com,myicqacc2@icq.com).
Please join my chat room:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10215/xmpp-protocol